# How to get value from axios post response into UI text element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How should I get the value from axios post response (`response.data.result`) into UI text element.

```
setRecorderState((prevState) => {
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file_from_react", blob, "1.wav");
      console.log(formData)
      axios
        .post("http://192.168.0.112:5000/profile", formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("response: " + response.data.result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response) {
            console.log(error.response);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
          }
        });
       
      if (prevState.mediaRecorder)
        return {
          ...initialState,
          audio: url,
        };
      else return initialState;
    });
```

The response is in `response.data.result`. The question is: how can i render this response in the HTML page, this page being located in another js file?
This is the main code for the HTML page, and I want to render the variable mentioned above here:

```
 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <div className="recorder-container">
        <RecorderControls recorderState={recorderState} handlers={handlers} />
        <RecordingsList audio={audio} />
      </div>
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: If these are in totally separate files, redux or react context would work. If the page you want to display the result in is a child of the parent, just use prop drilling. It's hard to say which solution is best for you because you did not specify how the files are related to one another

Comment: It's not recommended to call api inside your `setState`, instead you should call the api, get the value and then set the state.